# Legalities of sport TV in background? 

Tags: copyright, background, ambience, field-recording

For a movie I'm working on, I need some small rugby crowd ambiences. So I went to a pub to record some, but the TV was up a bit too present. It's non-distinct, but audible nonetheless.

My question is whether sport on TV (so a presenter, some crowds and some names of players and teams) is okay to record or are there legal implications?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

At least in the US (probably the same everywhere), you can't use it unless you can obtain permission from broadcaster who owns the rights, which you probably will not be able to do without some sort of contract and payment to the rights holder.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with above, but it sounds like a great reason to ply a bunch of friends with some foamy libations and record rugby walla, probably also doing a separate semi-ADR session with someone doing the play-by-play. I'd volunteer my voice and liver if I lived closer to ya. :-)

Comment: Nice idea. And fun too :-) 

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that it is the same in the UK, you can not include any broadcast content without it being licensed.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably illegal, but, then again, so is everything else.

If there's no likelihood of being sued, you should use it illegally to protest against the ever-encroaching tentacles of copyright law.